# Get selected tag from html file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a source of a page and I need to get all  tags from this file. Order is important. I need both external and inline scripts.  tag must be included in the output. I'm looking for a console linux tool.

I tried searching but I couldn't find anything, to the point I used jQuery to obtain this info and pasted it into a file. But this output has some strange encoding, so I need to parse it traditionally.

Example:
Input:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script1.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">...</div>
    <script src="footer.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
<script>alert('hello');</script>
<script src="footer.js">
```

Second example, output only src attibutes.

```
script1.js
script2.js
inline script 
footer.js
```

Comment: This question is not about programming. It's about obtaining data from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` for that and its only-matching parameter (`-o`), e.g.:

```
$ grep -o "<[^>]*>" <(curl -s http://example.com/)
```

This will print all the html tags including the order.

To include only `<script>` tags, try (change `index.html` with your file):

```
$ grep -Eo "<script.*(</script>|>)" index.html
```

For getting just the file names (from `src` attribute), you can extend by adding another `grep`, e.g.:

```
$ grep -Eo "<script.*(</script>|>)" index.html | grep -o '"[^"]*"' | tr -d '"'
```

Above syntax won't help you with many different variations of html code, therefore for more complex solutions, [using regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/55075) is in general not advised, therefore you should to use appropriate tools (language of your preference or check out these [shell tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263520/55075)).

Comment: I just want <script> tags and it is a local .html file.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to display only src attributes for external js, while displaying <script>... for inline scripts? Or if that's not possible, then only the former, just src attributes of script elements that have src attributes

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I know you've accepted an answer already, but I also want to add that you can look into [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

It's meant specifically for xml style data.

In your case, the xpath for this would be

```
//script
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/parsing-html-pages-using-xpath-1abf3fec991c) is also another example of someone using xpath to parse HTML